# downloading images from json, android

Tags: android, json, image, android-asynctask

my app receive a jsonArray that have names of categories and their images urls.
so i want to extract the names and also download the image by they urls.
actually i succeed to extract the names and also the urls, look at the code bellow:

```
            private class ReadPlacesFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>              {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray categories = new JSONArray(
                    jsonobject.getString("categories"));
            for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject category = categories.getJSONObject(i);
                names.add(category.getString("name"));
                images.add(category.getString("image"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getBaseContext(), R.layout.row_channel_layout,
                R.id.channel_name, names);
        channel_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.channel_list);
        channel_list.setAdapter(adapter);




    }
}
```

my questions:
1. is it ok to build the adapter in the onPostExecute method ?
2.should i write another a synctasck class to download the images?,or extract the urls in doInbackground method and after that download the images, and return both of the images and the names to onPostExecute method.
actually i try this and i think it is very slow because decoding the json in the background method is very slow !
3.how could i build the listView after downloading the names, then after downloading the images, i just modify it.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Typically yes, though your better to make the adapter then pass the values to it on the post execute then call adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

2: I recommend not reinventing the wheel and using the "fantastic" picasso image loading library

```
http://square.github.io/picasso/
```

3: Create one listview, pass the names and urls to it, make the array adapter into your own custom e.g. "myListAdapter" which then sets the name value and then using picasso download and load the image into your imageview or whatever else you want to do with it.

```
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom
```

E.g.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ArrayList<String> myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.row_category_layout,R.id.category_name, names);
        //execute my data task

    }


    public void dataTask()
    {

        //GOT SOME DATA
        myListItems.add("MYDATA");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: thank your for your fast response, regarding to my first question, how could i build the adapter at the oncreate method(for example) and i already don't have the names of the categories because i am waiting until the asynctask finish downloading, which names should i pass to it at first. :) thanks

Comment: It's really up to you, i personally pass in the empty ArrayList, if you did it inside the result method you'd create another adapter every single time its run, not good for performance.

Comment: yes i agree with you, but does it possible to modify the adapter after i create it, because in that way i will still with empty list and this what happened to me

Comment: Yes, thats 'Exactly' what 'adapter.notifDataSetChanged();' does, literally just e.g.  myArrayList.add("myitem"); followed by 'adapter.notifDataSetChanged();' and the list will update to reflect.

Comment: new ReadPlacesFeedTask().execute("http://example.com");ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_category_layout,R.id.category_name, names);
category_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.category_list);
category_list.setAdapter(adapter); this what i did in Oncreate method and that did not work, this what do you mean ?